# How to fill data into xml format?

Tags: android, xml, sqlite, export

I have a huge amount of data (200 pages) and i need to import it to sqlite database through XML(in android)

i want to parse xml data and save it to db in android...

i want these data available from the first installing the app...

i want to know what is the easiest way to import data into XML format...

because data is too much lengthy i need some help from you to solve it easier...

what is the easiest way to achieve to suitable xml format

is there any software to handle this problem or should done manually???

how to put data in xml format ?

Answer (score 0):

use [simpleframework](http://simple.sourceforge.net/).

It is a java xml serialization/deserialization library which is pretty easy to use.

I used it in my last android app and it works really well.